# vim: multiple "sessions" in the same instance?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I work on a growing project with vim. I like to have most of the project files open in the same session. However, as the project's growing, I start to have too many files open at the same time; switching between files **[*]** starts getting a bit unproductive at 40+ files because the list gets too long (for, say, 20 files this way of navigating works very well for me, however).

**Is there a way to split the session in multiple "sub-sessions" in the same instance of vim?**

How I imagine it is that each session would contain, say, 20 files and only list those with `:ls`, and that I could switch between them in the same vim window (basicallly the same as if I'd run multiple instances of vim in the same shell and switch between them with `Ctrl-Z; fg %X`, just without leaving vim).

***[*]*** I like to navigate between files with `:ls` followed by `:bX` (or directly `:bX` in case I've memorized a buffer number), along with `:bp`/`:bn`, and I always have at least two split open, and this workflow works quite well for me, so I'm not looking for more efficient alternatives to `:ls`.

Comment: What's the issue that you are facing? In your question, you talk about your current workflow "getting a bit unproductive" (without explaining what that means to you), but in your comment on Luc's answer, you're talking about file size of the session.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're still facing the same issue, you might see if there's an answer on the [Vim beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use `:ls`. However I often work on big projects, and I open (many) files from different projects (and I'm still able to compile what I want in the mode I want (debug, release, ...), generate tags independently for each project, have different coding styles, etc)

Your question seems to be about "How do I go from one file to another". I have many split windows opened simultaneously and I jump from one to the other with:

- `:sb`, which supports tab completion on filenames (already opened in buffer)
- `:sp **/filename*<tab>` (When it's not already opened)
- an old [plugin of mine](https://github.com/LucHermitte/SearchInRuntime) -- others usually use Unite, command-T or other similar plugins -- to merge `:sp` and `:sb` into one command.
- Tags. The default integration of tags (/csope) is already nice. Yet, I've developed [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags), in order to simply the tags navigation in a world of overloaded and overridden functions as it's the case in C++.

EDIT: I've just pushed a highly experimental `:Project <name> :ls` feature in [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/project/doc/Project.md). Note: this new *project* feature wasn't meant to do what you're looking for, but it's easy to have a restricted `:ls` thanks to it.

To use it, you'll have to first register buffers to one project or another. Here, I recommend plugins like [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) if each project can be distinguished as files under a given directory. For each root directory place a `_vimrc_local.vim` file in it that'll contain:

```
:let s:k_version = 1
" Global definitions executed everytime we enter a file belonging to the project
" This is where we set g:lobal_variables and options for project-unaware plugins.
....

" Then the anti-reinclusion guards for buffer definitions
if &cp || (exists("b:loaded__my_foobar_project_settings")
      \ && (b:loaded__my_foobar_project_settings > s:k_version)
      \ && !exists('g:force_reload__my_foobar_project_settings'))
  finish
endif
let b:loaded__my_foobar_project_settings = s:k_version
let s:cpo_save=&cpo
set cpo&vim

" HERE, we say the current buffer belongs to a project
" solution 1 when we need more control
:call lh#project#define(s:, {'name': 'YouProjectName'})
" OR solution 2 which is easier to manipulate (tab completion, ...)
:Project --define YourProjectName
```

You can also have a smaller granularity if you wish (this is something which is still poorly documented).

Then, you'll be able to consult the list of projects with `:Project --list`, or to consult the buffers associated to a given project with `:Project YouProjectName :ls`.

Comment: Tanks for your suggestions, I wasn't aware of `:sb` which looks handy. However, the question is not so much about "how to get from one file to another"; `:ls` followed by `:bX` (or directly `bX` once I've memorized the number of a buffer) alongside `:bn`/`:bp` works well enough for me. The main problem is really that the session gets a bit big, and I'd like to avoid using multiple instances of vim in different tmux windows (though that would likely be the way to go if something similar to what I've discribed in the question is not possible).

Comment: That's the thing: you don't need to memorize buffer numbers to open the buffer in the current window. `:sb` and `:b` support tab completion on part on the buffer filename. We really don't need `:ls` to know buffer numbers in order to load these opened buffers in the current window.

Comment: Otherwise, at best, there are tabs, but still, everything will be visible by `:ls`

Comment: Which make me think. I'm currently working on a [new project feature](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/project/doc/Project.md) in my lh-vim-lib -- I'm mainly in the need to write the docs, and use it in my other plugins steps. It would be quite easy to add a `:Ls <projectname>` to display buffers associated to the active projects.

Comment: Thanks for the edit regarding `lh-vim-lib`, I'll try it out as soon as I find some time!

Comment: In the mean time, I've simplified Project creation -> `:Project --define ProjectName`

Comment: For what its worth, I don't use `:ls` either, I just type `:b `, start typing the file name and hit TAB key to complete